# grunt-processhtml blocking tasks

Tags: html, replace, process, gruntjs

For my grunt task I am trying to put the markup from my development environment into JSP files. When I run the task initially when the files have not been included for instance

```
  <!-- build:include:dist ../../source/html/views/include/head.dust -->
    {>"include/head.dust"/}
  <!-- /build -->
```

I get expected results, the head.dust is inserted in this code block.

However, if I run this again on the same file once the block was inserted, the whole grunt task freezes. I was expecting it to either update or move to the next task. Is it possible with this grunt task or should I use another task to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem seems to be using the source and destination as the same file for the tasks. Instead I created a template as source and used the destination as a seperate file